# MIPS Assembly Program Not Performing Lines

Tags: arrays, assembly, macros, mips, mars-simulator

I am currently using MIPS Assembly. I have recently learned how to do both macros and arrays (of a sort), so I promptly wrote a fairly simple program to test them out. However, between getting the data and displaying it again, I wish to output a new message. For some reason, my program doesn't appear to do this, even though when running through it step by step it DOES, in fact, go through those lines - it just simply doesn't have any output. Is there any particular reason in MIPS Assembly why this isn't working, or is it a glitch in the MARS assembler?

```
.data
    testlist: .word 50
    request: .asciiz "Enter pi up to 50 digits: 3."
    out: .asciiz "\nPi: 3."
.text
.macro arraygetword(%initaddress,%offset,%storeto)
    la $a1,%initaddress
    mul $a0,%offset,4
    add $a0,$a0,$a1
    lw %storeto,($a0)
.end_macro
.macro arraysetword(%initaddress,%offset,%value)
    la $a1,%initaddress
    mul $a0,%offset,4
    add $a0,$a0,$a1
    sw %value,($a0)
.end_macro
.macro arraygetbyte(%initaddress,%offset,%storeto)
    la $a1,%initaddress
    add $a0,%offset,$a1
    lw %storeto,($a0)
.end_macro
.macro arraysetbyte(%initaddress,%offset,%value)
    la $a1,%initaddress
    add $a0,%offset,$a1
    sw %value,($a0)
.end_macro
main:   
    la $a0,request
    li $v0,4
    syscall
    li $t0,0
    li $t1,50
forloop:
    li $v0,12
    syscall
    arraysetword(testlist,$t0,$v0)# testlist[$t0]=$v0
    addi $t0,$t0,1
    blt $t0,$t1,forloop

    li $t0,0
    li $t1,50

    la $a0,out# This is the part not working.
    li $v0,4#   Why doth this not output anything?
    syscall#    I need some sort of line break. It's awkward otherwise.
output:
    arraygetword(testlist,$t0,$a0)# $a0=testlist[$t0]
    li $v0,11
    syscall
    addi $t0,$t0,1
    blt $t0,$t1,output

    li $v0,10
    syscall
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`testlist: .word 50` does **not** allocate 50 words, it allocates a single word with value 50. As such, your program is overwriting the memory after it, which contains your strings to print. Of course by that time you have already printed the `request` so that is not affected.

Comment: While this helped me find the error, for others looking, I'd like to add that to fix it, I changed it from .word to .space and multiplied the number by 4, since a word is four times the size of a byte, to allocate the space properly. Thanks!

Comment: @Bioniclegenius Quick note, `.space` does not word align you addresses which may cause a problem. Either proceed `.space` with an `.align 2` or use `.word 0:50`

Comment: THAT'S what I was looking for originally! Thank you so much. .word 0:50 is certainly the easiest and most concise solution.